# I have some doubts in python project. Somebody help me

Tags: python, django, project

Why should a python project contain context_processors.py in its app?
If its a just snippet why should not we use other names?
Why should it is specifically it coined as context_processors.py?

Comment: It's just django's convention, not Python's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application can contain (it's not obligate) context_processors.py if you want to put some variables in Template Context object. These vars are global in your templates.

You can name this file whatever you like but it is common name in Django (like middleware.py, views.py and others). It will be clear for other developers who will support your code later.

Django project includes this file using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your settings.py

Answer (score 2):

I assume your question is about naming conventions?

In this case, it is advisable to follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especially the following section:

> **Package and Module Names**
>
> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.  Underscores can be used
>    in the module name if it improves readability.  Python packages should
>    also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is
>    discouraged.